# Julia JuMP slowdown/hang while solving TSP

Tags: julia, linear-programming, julia-jump

Trying to optimize a linear programming problem on JuMP (traveling salesman problem)

The basic model runs fine, but the second model (with subtour elimination) makes Julia unresponsive when I try to run it, I've left it running for the past 15 minutes and still nothing

The basic model (works fine):

```
D = zeros(58,58) #the actual dataset is irrelevant to the freezing problem

#basic method (no subtour elimination)

using JuMP
using GLPK
using Formatting

n = 58;
N = collect(1:n);

m = Model(GLPK.Optimizer)

@variable(m, x[i in N, j in N], Bin);

@objective(m, Min, sum(x[i,j] * D[i,j] for i in N for j in N));

@constraint(m, [i in N], sum(x[i,j] for j in N) == 1);
@constraint(m, [j in N], sum(x[i,j] for i in N) == 1);

@constraint(m, [i in N], x[i,i] == 0);

optimize!(m)

printfmt("Minimal cost (basic TSP) == {:d}\n",objective_value(m))
```

The second model (hangs on !optimize(m)):

```
#subtour elimination using potential method

@variable(m, p[i in N], Int);

@constraint(m, [i in N], 1 <= p[i] <= n);

@constraint(m, p[1] == 1);

for i in N
    for j in 2:n
        if i != j
            @constraint(m, p[i] - p[j] + n*x[i,j] <= n - 1); #having this constraint on makes the solver freeze
        end
    end
end

optimize!(m) #solver freezes here

printfmt("Minimal cost (potential method) == {:d}\n",objective_value(m))
```

Tried to make a different model for the second one instead of just adding to the first one, tried to separate each model into a function, tried alternate formulations for the same method, nothing works

What am I doing wrong with my code? I can't tell if Julia is completely frozen or just ungodly slow

Comment: The MILP representation of TSP scales exponentially. With GLPK you will probably solve something around 20-25. The best you can do is Gurobi (there is a free academic license) + lazy constraints, this should get you to somewhere around 35. If this is what you need update the question and I can post you sample code. For bigger problems try     TravelingSalesmanHeuristics.jl which works really well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding all of the subtler elimination constraints, you can use an iterative method, or write a callback.

See the JuMP documentation for more details: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/tutorials/algorithms/tsp_lazy_constraints/

You could also try a different solver, like HiGHS or Gurobi. GLPK is quite slow at solving MILPs.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a few variants of your model. With Cplex as solver using 58 cities (randomly placed, Euclidian distances, default solver settings), I see:

```
----    180 PARAMETER stats  collected statistics

                           obj  iterations       nodes     seconds

MTZ(int u)             569.089 1061905.000   83982.000      27.578
MTZ(relaxed u)         569.089 1153378.000   77797.000      22.953
lifted(int u)          569.089 1623901.000  105898.000      20.094
lifted(relaxed u)      569.089 1287205.000   73390.000      18.610
lift+vi(int u)         569.089  365546.000   27155.000       4.735
lift+vi(relaxed u)     569.089  887140.000   60696.000      14.406
```

I called your `p` variables `u` in my model. The slowest version (basic MTZ) takes less than half a minute.

Your version is called MTZ, published a long time ago:

```
 Miller, C., A. Tucker, R. Zemlin. 1960, Integer programming 
 formulation of traveling salesman problems. J. ACM 7 326-329
```

The lifted versions are taken from:

```
Desrochers, M., Laporte, G., Improvements and extensions to the 
Miller-Tucker-Zemlin subtour elimination constraints, Operations 
Research Letters, 10 (1991) 27-36.
```

Conclusion: MTZ is known to be slow, but 58 cities is well within the reach of a good solver.

The gory details are in [here](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2023/08/some-tsp-mtz-experiments.html).